# Codedom and string handling

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, codedom

I've researched on this but couldn't find anything solid and wanted to see if someone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to see if Codedom can handle strings and concantination between different languages, without me setting up conditional strings per language.

For example, I need to generate the following *exactly as shown below* in both C# and VB.NET via Codedom:

**C#**

```
errorMsg = errorMsg.Replace('"', '\'').Replace("\r\n", @"\n");
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + errorMsg + "\");");
```

**VB.NET**

```
errorMsg = errorMsg.Replace(""""c, "'"c).Replace(ChrW(13) & ChrW(10), "\n")
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("throw new Error(""Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + errorMsg + """);")
```

The `CodeMethodInvokeExpression` for `errorMsg.Replace` and `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval` is simple enough, it's the string inside them that I can't figure out if Codedom can automatically handle.

Comment: I don't understand your C# example.  Your string literal contains two double quotes in a row.  That is not legal C#.  Ironically, your VB.NET example, for the literal, is valid C#, so why not just use that?

Comment: @Kirk Woll: The example is not mine, it's Microsoft's. This is what is generated in App.xaml.vb or App.xaml.cs for a new Silverlight project in VS. What it appears to be doing is kicking an error message over to Javascript.

Comment: But I do not see how the MS example could possibly compile.  Are you suggesting that it does?

Comment: I'm with Kirk Woll on this one, I dont see how that C# can compile

Comment: It compiles all the time. Give it a try yourself. Create a new Silverlight project in VS2008 or VS2010. See that the above code is in the `ReportErrorToDOM` routine in *App.xaml.cs*. Compile.

Comment: I just did exactly what you suggested.  This is what I see in my App.xaml.cs:

System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + errorMsg + "\");");

This does **not** mach your example above:

System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("throw new Error(""Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + errorMsg + """);")

Comment: Ugh, my sincere apologies, I had the VB and C# ones backwards.

Comment: @Kirk woll just to confuse things in C# "" can actually be valid in a string literal but _only_ if the format of the literal is @"...".

Comment: @Rune, no, that's not true at all.  Otherwise how would you close the string literal?  Did you even try it? ;)

Comment: @Kirk yes I did try it and yes it's working :). If that was not the case how would you escape a " in the string? you can't use \ for escaping it's a literal so \" would simply be interpreted as backslah and then the " would be the ending qoute. and for closing the literal I would simply use a single ". Try it out and you'll see it works as long as you start the literal with @" and not "

Comment: @Rune, I tried it before posting.  You are totally wrong here.  To wit:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx:  single-verbatim-string-literal-character:  **Any character except "**

Comment: @Kirk: interesting link you put there. To be honest could have found a better my eslf :) "In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence" and 'quote-escape-sequence:
""' with the example code also from MSDN: 
string f = @"Joe said ""Hello"" to me";   // Joe said "Hello" to me.

Comment: @Rune, you're absolutely correct.  I did try it too, but must have been something wrong with my example when I did.  Thanks for being stubborn in your disagreement with me.  Let me learn something new. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately code primitives, when combined, don’t always produce desired results because the provider will take certain liberties to interpret intent. The way around this is to use a [CodeSnippetExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codesnippetexpression.aspx).

Here’s code (VB.NET & C#) that works to produce the Eval statements that you listed in your question.  Feel free to use whichever works best for you:

**VB.NET Version**

```
Imports System.CodeDom
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.CSharp

Public Class PrintEvalStatement
    Public provider As CodeDomProvider

    Sub New()
        Dim left As New CodePrimitiveExpression("throw new Error(""Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application ")
        Dim middle As New CodeVariableReferenceExpression("errorMsg")
        Dim right As New CodePrimitiveExpression(""");")

        Dim targetObject = New CodeTypeReferenceExpression("System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window")
        Dim methodName = "Eval"

        provider = New VBCodeProvider()
        Dim vbStatement As String = ConcatStatement(left, middle, right, targetObject, methodName)

        provider = New CSharpCodeProvider()
        Dim csStatement As String = ConcatStatement(left, middle, right, targetObject, methodName)

        Console.WriteLine(vbStatement)
        Console.WriteLine(csStatement)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Function ConcatStatement(ByVal left As CodePrimitiveExpression,
                                     ByVal middle As CodeVariableReferenceExpression,
                                     ByVal right As CodePrimitiveExpression,
                                     ByVal targetObject As CodeTypeReferenceExpression,
                                     ByVal methodName As String) As String
        Dim evalMessage As New CodeExpression
        evalMessage = ConcatString(left, middle, right)

        Dim eval As New CodeMethodInvokeExpression(targetObject, methodName, evalMessage)
        Dim evalStatement As New CodeExpressionStatement(eval)
        Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter()

        Using tx As TextWriter = New StringWriter()
            provider.GenerateCodeFromStatement(evalStatement, tx, New CodeGeneratorOptions())
            Return tx.ToString()
        End Using
    End Function
    Private Function ConcatString(ByVal left As CodeExpression,
                                  ByVal middle As CodeExpression,
                                  ByVal right As CodeExpression) As CodeExpression
        Return New CodeSnippetExpression(CodeToString(left) + " + " + CodeToString(middle) + " + " + CodeToString(right))
    End Function
    Private Function CodeToString(ByVal expr As CodeExpression) As String
        Using tx As TextWriter = New StringWriter()
            provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(expr, tx, New CodeGeneratorOptions())
            Return tx.ToString()
        End Using
    End Function


End Class
```

**C# Version**

```
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace CodeDom
{
    class Program
    {       
        static CodeDomProvider provider;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program shell = new Program();
            provider = new VBCodeProvider();
            CodePrimitiveExpression left = new CodePrimitiveExpression("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application\")");
            CodeVariableReferenceExpression middle = new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("errorMsg");
            CodePrimitiveExpression right = new CodePrimitiveExpression("\");");

            CodeTypeReferenceExpression targetObject = new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window");
            string methodName = "Eval";

            string vbStatement =  shell.ConcatStatement(left, middle, right, targetObject, methodName);

            provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

            string csStatement = shell.ConcatStatement(left, middle, right, targetObject, methodName);

            Console.WriteLine(vbStatement);
            Console.WriteLine(csStatement);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public string ConcatStatement(CodePrimitiveExpression left, CodeVariableReferenceExpression middle, CodePrimitiveExpression right, CodeTypeReferenceExpression targetObject, string methodName)
        {
            CodeExpression evalMessage = new CodeExpression();
            evalMessage = ConcatString(left, middle, right);

            CodeMethodInvokeExpression eval = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(targetObject, methodName, evalMessage);
            CodeExpressionStatement evalStatement = new CodeExpressionStatement(eval);
            using (TextWriter tx = new StringWriter())
            {
                provider.GenerateCodeFromStatement(evalStatement, tx, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
                return tx.ToString();
            }
        }

        private CodeExpression ConcatString(CodeExpression left, CodeExpression middle, CodeExpression right) {
            return new CodeSnippetExpression(CodeToString(left) + " + " + CodeToString(middle) + " + " + CodeToString(right));
        }

        private string CodeToString(CodeExpression expr) {
            using (TextWriter tx = new StringWriter()) {
                provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(expr,tx, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
                return tx.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:
I just tried the following code:

```
VBCodeProvider vbProvider = new VBCodeProvider();
CSharpCodeProvider csProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

var errorMessagePart1 = new CodePrimitiveExpression("Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application \"");
var errorMessagePart2 = new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("errorMsg");
var errorMessagePart3 = new CodePrimitiveExpression("\"");
var errorMessage = new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(errorMessagePart1, CodeBinaryOperatorType.Add, errorMessagePart2), CodeBinaryOperatorType.Add, errorMessagePart3);
var expression = new CodeThrowExceptionStatement(new CodeObjectCreateExpression("Error", errorMessage));

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
vbProvider.GenerateCodeFromStatement(expression, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
string vb = writer.ToString();
writer = new StringWriter();
csProvider.GenerateCodeFromStatement(expression, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
string cs = writer.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(vb);
Console.WriteLine(cs);
```

It prints out:

```
Throw New [Error]((("Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application """ + errorMsg) _ 
    + """"))

throw new Error((("Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application \"" + errorMsg)
    + "\""));
```

Which looks to me like a VB version and a C# version.  Not a whole lot you can do about the spurious parentheses, but shouldn't cause any harm.

Comment: +1. A valiant effort, really interesting how you did that. Unfortunately I need the whole thing as a string and haven't been able to work that out from the ode above.

Answer (score 1):

You could call string.Concat instead of using the + operator unless you need to generate the code exactly as shown.

```
CodePrimitiveExpression throwstring = new CodePrimitiveExpression("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application ");
CodeVariableReferenceExpression errorMsg = new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("errorMsg");
CodePrimitiveExpression end = new CodePrimitiveExpression("\");");

CodeTypeReferenceExpression targetObject = new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window");
CodeTypeReferenceExpression str = new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(string));
CodeMethodInvokeExpression concat = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(str,"Concat",throwstring,errorMsg,end);
CodeMethodInvokeExpression invoke = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new CodeMethodReferenceExpression(targetObject, "Eval"), concat);
```

Outputs C#:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval(string.Concat("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application ", errorMsg, "\");"))
```

VB:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval(String.Concat("throw new Error(""Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application ", errorMsg, """);"))
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't really help much. As stated in the question above, I need to generate those strings/statements. I'll edit the question to add the words "exactly as shown below".

Answer (score 0):

The class `CodeTypeReference` should help you (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypereference.aspx), just as Alison used.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't particularly helpful.